# Get total value by Javascript in laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I try to get shipment price sum to my cart total price by ajax.

What I have so far:

1. Getting total price of cart.
2. Getting price list of shipping methods.

What I want to do is to `sum` this 2 values together.

**example:**

`Cart Total:` 20.000
`Shipping Cost:` 10.000

`Total:` 30.000

## My Codes

**Controller:**

```
//Select shipping method to sum with total price of cart
    public function totalPriceInTotal(Request $request, $postchoose) {
      $totalPriceIn = $request->input('postchoose');
      return response()->json($totalPriceIn);
    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/totalPriceInTotal/{postchoose}','CartController@totalPriceInTotal');
```

**View:**

```
//HTML
<div class="panel-body" id="totalPriceInTotal">

</div>


//JavaScript
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="postchoose"]').on('change', function() {
      var destinationPrice = $(this).val();
      if(destinationPrice) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('totalPriceInTotal') }}/'+encodeURI(destinationPrice),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
          $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
          $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>' + {{Cart::getTotal()}} + $totalPriceIn + '</p>');
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**My Network Result:**

[image: screen1]

> PS: **All I need is to `sum` that `37000` with my cart total price**.

## UPDATE:

this how I get my shipping data on dropdown and select that `37000` from it:

```
success:function(data) {
                $('#des').empty();
                $('#des').append(
                  '<p>Destination: ' + data['meta']['destination']['province'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['type'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['city_name'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['postal_code'] +'</p>'
                  );
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                  $('#info').empty();
                  $('select[name="postchoose"]').empty();
                  $('#info').append('<h3>'+ value['code'] + '<small>' + value['name'] +'</small></h3>');
                    $.each(value.costs, function(key2, value2) {
                      $.each(value2.cost, function(key3, value3) {

                        // number format
                        var number = value3['value'];
                        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                            maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                            minimumFractionDigits:0
                        });

                        var formattedNumber = nf.format(number);
                        // number format
                        $('select[name="postchoose"]').append('<option id="postchoose" class="form-control" name="postchoose" value="'+ value3['value'] +'">'+ value2['service'] + ' - ' + nf.format(number) + ' Rp' + ' - ' + value3['etd'] + ' hari' +'</option>');
                      });
                    });
                });
              }
```

Comment: is `$totalPriceIn` a javascript variable declared there, or is generated by laravel?

Comment: is generated by laravel `controller function`

Comment: @CholNhial any idea?

Comment: You can use local storage to store cart total, and then you need to parse the value returned using `parseFloat` I will post the answer.

Comment: Your mixing of Laravel and AJAX calls is not very good. But maybe you should do this:
`$('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>' + data + destinationPrice + '</p>');` Since both the values are already on the browser side.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed it was returning `object object`. And please if you think another way would be better to achieve this share an answer thank you.

Comment: Better way would be seperate AJAX and templating engine, but I dunno how well it applies to you.

Comment: Also, maybe you should send an Associative array in the response to solve that `object object` issue. Like `response()->json(['total'=>$totalPriceIn]);` and on the JS side instead of `data` use `data.total`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this in you script on success hope this will help

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="postchoose"]').on('change', function() {
     var destinationPrice = $(this).val();
    if(destinationPrice) {
     $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url('totalPriceInTotal') }}/'+ destinationPrice,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data) {
      var value= parseFloat(data)+parseFloat({{Cart::getTotal()}});

       $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
      $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
    }
  });
  }else{
    $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
  }
});
```

});

Comment: `ReferenceError: $totalPriceIn is not defined`

Comment: another thing, what happen to my {{Cart::getTotal()}}?

Comment: i saw :), i get `undefined24524` where 24524 is my `totalcart` and undefined is that `37000`

Comment: @mafortis what is this  {{Cart::getTotal()}} did you make any function outside controller for eg:- app/cart  folder if yes did you register in app.php

Comment: that is my total price of cart it comes from my cart package. https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

Comment: Return... `NaN`

Comment: @mafortis you are encoding "(destinationPrice)" but you are not decoding it in controller

Comment: no i don't encode,decode anything. data are from third-part website and i just looped data to get results.

Comment: i get `NaN` on it

Comment: @mafortis i saw i problem in controller    public function totalPriceInTotal(Request $request, $postchoose) {
      $totalPriceIn = $postchoose;
      return response()->json($totalPriceIn);
    }   try this and tell me what you are getting

Comment: returns... `NaN`

Comment: @mafortis in success alert(data.totalPriceIn) what you are getting

Comment: Wait!//////////

Comment: yep undefined! :)

Comment: found it! just remove `totalPriceIn` use data

Comment: `var value= parseFloat(data)+parseFloat({{Cart::getTotal()}});
          $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
          $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');` not returning value \m/. how do I number format it?

Comment: @mafortis to thank me upvote my answer this will help other

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$totalPriceIn` is provided by template engine, here's what might work. I'm using local storage.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

  if(!localStorage.getItem('cartTotal')) {
    var cartTotal = {{Cart::getTotal()}};
    localStorage.setItem('cartTotal', cartTotal);
  }

  $('select[name="postchoose"]').on('change', function() {
    var destinationPrice = $(this).val();
    if(destinationPrice) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url('totalPriceInTotal') }}/'+encodeURI(destinationPrice),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data) {
        var cartTotalPrice = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('cartTotal'));
        $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
        $('#totalPriceInTotal').append('<p>' +  (cartTotalPrice + parseFloat(data)) + $totalPriceIn + '</p>');
        localStorage.removeItem('cartTotal');
      }
    });
    }else{
      $('#totalPriceInTotal').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `{{Cart::getTotal()}}` is coming from my cart package data are stored in session, i don't think if i need to store it again. what do you think?  `package` https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

Comment: then I think it should be possible to do this if that what you want `( {{Cart::getTotal()}} + parseFloat(data) )`

Comment: you do still believe i should store my cartTotal again?

Comment: If it will work without using local storage then go for it.

Comment: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: `TypeError: Storage.getItem is not a function`

Comment: I have revised the answer. See changes.